# How to find the transformation matrix from input/output?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I need some help with the following question - I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Can someone point me in the right direction?

> Let $T$: ${\rm I\!R}^3$ -> ${\rm I\!R}^2$ be a linear transformation
>   with $T(1,-1,2) = (1,1)$ and $T(-3,1,1)=(1,-1)$. Find $T(-11,5,-1)$.
>   Alternatively, explain why this is impossible without more
>   information.

$$\begin{pmatrix}1 \\\ -1 \\\ 2\end{pmatrix} => \begin{pmatrix}1 \\\ 1\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\\ 1 \\\ 1\end{pmatrix} => \begin{pmatrix}1 \\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$

How can I determine the transformation matrix from this information? (Or what information am I missing that I would need to figure it out?)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what $T$ being a _linear_ transformation means? You'll have to apply the definition of _linear_ to the information you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$(-11,5,-1)=-2(1,−1,2)+3(-3,1,1).$$Therefore$$T(-11,5,-1)=-2T(1,-1,2)+3T(-3,1,1).$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh - I was thinking about the problem all wrong. Thanks, I got it now!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking if looking for the matrix associated with this linear transformation from $\mathbb{R^3}$ to $\mathbb{R^2}$ is a good way. Let us go in this direction. Necessarily, this matrix has 2 rows and 3 columns :

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{pmatrix}$$

with respect to the canonical bases in each separate space ($\mathbb{R^3}$ and $\mathbb{R^2}$) ; why that ? In order that this product :

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\d&e&f\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}X \\ Y\end{pmatrix}$$

is possible.

Having constraints :

$$M\begin{pmatrix} \ \ 1 \\ -1 \\ \ \ 2\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 1\end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ M\begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ \ \ 1 \\ \ \ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \ \ 1 \\\ -1\end{pmatrix}$$

yield a linear system of 4 equations with 6 unknowns, 
$$\begin{cases}a-b+2c&=&1\\
-3a+b+c&=&1\\
d-e+2f&=&1\\
-3d+e+f&=&-1\end{cases}$$
which isn't enough to conclude... (underdetermined system : infinite number of solutions).

But here, we are in an **exceptional case** where one doesn't need to compute the enties $a,b,c,d,e,f$ because

$$\begin{pmatrix} \ \ 1 \\ -1 \\ \ \ 2\end{pmatrix} \ \text{is a linear combination of} \ \begin{pmatrix} \ \ 1 \\ -1 \\ \ \ 2\end{pmatrix} \ \text{and} \  \begin{pmatrix}-3 \\ \ \ 1 \\ \ \ 1\end{pmatrix} $$

as shown in the answer by @José Carlos Santos.

Comment: I have rectify my answer which was wrong because it didn't take into account that we are in an exceptional case...